# jQuery not affecting text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to get jQuery to affect with my text input - What should be happening is that I should be able to scroll the the alphabet in my text form by hitting the up and down arrow keys, but this is not happening. The text form is instantiated like this - `jQuery('#canvas').after('<div id="user-name-input"><input type="text" id="scrollLetters:/></div>');`

As expected, the initial value in the text box is " _ ", but when I press the up or down arrow, there is no affect. It should turn " _ " to "A", and with another key press "B", and so on. Perhaps this has something to do with where the cursor is being focused?

```
     var letterIndex = 0;

     function replaceLetter(index, charCode, originalString){
     originalString = originalString.substr(0, index) + 
     String.fromCharCode(charCode) + originalString.substr(index + 
     String.fromCharCode(charCode).length);
     console.log("new", originalString);
     $("#scrollLetters").val(originalString);

    }
   function addBlank(){
    $("#scrollLetters").val(  $("#scrollLetters").val() + "_" );
  }
  function removeBlank(){
$("#scrollLetters").val(  $("#scrollLetters").val().slice(0,-1) );
 }

    $("body").keydown(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var originalString = $("#scrollLetters").val();
    console.log(originalString);
    var charCode = originalString.charCodeAt(letterIndex);
    console.log("charCode ", charCode);

switch (e.which){
    case 38:    //up arrow key
        if((charCode == 95) || (charCode == 97))
            //charCode = 122;
        //else if(charCode == 97)
            charCode = 122;
        else
            charCode--;

        replaceLetter(letterIndex, charCode, originalString);
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
        if( (charCode == 95) || (charCode == 122))

            charCode = 97;
        else
            charCode++;


        replaceLetter(letterIndex, charCode, originalString);
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        if ((letterIndex == originalString.length-1) && (charCode == 95)){
            console.log("already having a blank spot");
            break;
        }else if((letterIndex == originalString.length-1) && (charCode != 95)){
            addBlank();
        }
        letterIndex++;
        break;
    case 37:    //left arrow key
        if ((originalString.charCodeAt( originalString.length - 1) == 95) && letterIndex > 0)
            removeBlank();
        if(letterIndex > 0)
            letterIndex--;
        break;
    case 13:    // SUBMIT - change here whatever you want to do with the name
        // also here i would make sure that the user actually did enter a name
        let s = originalString; 
        if ((originalString.charCodeAt( originalString.length - 1) == 95) && letterIndex > 0)
            s = s.slice(0,-1);
        let h = document.createElement("p");
        h.innerHTML = "YOUR NAME IS " + s + " !";
        document.body.appendChild(h);
        break;
        }
        });

     function replaceAt(index, replacement, myLetters) {
     return myLetters.substr(0, index) + replacement+ 
     myLetters.substr(index + replacement.length);
     }


function nameInputField(action, data) { /* TIVLABS */
    switch(action) {
        case 'focus':
            jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
       input').find('input').focus();
        break;
        case 'value':
            return jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-input').length > 
         0 ? jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-
      input').find('input').val().toUpperCase() : '';
        break;
        case 'submit_btn':
            if(typeof(data) != 'undefined') {
                jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-input').find('input').data('submitbtn', data).keyup(function(e) {
                    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if(key == 13
                    && typeof(jQuery(this).data('submitbtn')) != 'undefined') {
                        var submit_btn = jQuery(this).data('submitbtn');
                        if(typeof(submit_btn.buttonRelease) != 'undefined')
                            submit_btn.buttonRelease();
                    }
                });
            }
        break;
        case 'remove':
            jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-input').empty().remove();
        break;
        case 'add':
        default:
            jQuery('#canvas').after('<div id="user-name-input"><input type=text id=scrollLetters readonly=true value=_ /></div>');
            jQuery('#canvas').next('#user-name-input').find('input').on('keydown keyup', function(e) { jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '').slice(0, 18)); });
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you closed the quotes in `id="scrollLetters"`?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] by removing code that is irrelevant to your question, and clarify what you mean by "get jQuery to play nice". What specifically is not working as you expect?

Comment: @MJr yes, that was a typo on my end.    I am unable to get jQuery to affect  my text input - What should be happening is that I should be able to scroll the the alphabet in my text form by hitting the up and down arrow keys, but this is not happening.

Comment: What do you mean with "scroll the alphabet"?

Comment: @DanielBeck  I edited the original post (I hope it is more clear  now)

Comment: iterate from a-z, like how an old arcade machine works when entering initals

Comment: You have several instances of line breaks inside your selectors (`#user-name-input` has a break before the "input" for example).  Correcting those syntax errors and removing a lot of `console.log`s that were lagging things causes this script to work as is.  Keep the browser error console open! It makes this sort of problem much easier to spot.

Comment: (That said, I'm not sure it's a great idea to hang a `keydown` event handler on the `body`; you should probably attach it to the form field instead of the entire page.)

Comment: @DanielBeck - were you able to get a working version? Unfortunately when hit a key, instead of seeing a new letter, the pre populated character of " _ " disappears...

Comment: Yes, see https://jsfiddle.net/xeqsoL77/2/